# Calling JS "link" attribute using "onclick" event

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, attributes

Code has been updated.

I'm trying to change all my hard coded links into a one attribute using **Onclick** event, so it would easy to me to change them all by changing just the attribute at the Head. The link is opened in an iframe.

This is my existing link. It does two things **simultaneously**:

1. Open some external webpage in a new window.
2. Calling another external webpage into my page.

I have many links like this, and I would like to use a script that will hold just the Onclick parameters and the iFrame name, instead of writing them again and again. The HREF link should be stay as is.

```
 <a href="www.SomeWebsiteInNewWindow.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" onClick=document.getElementById("MyFrame").src='www.CallingThe SourceOfMyFrame.com';>A link that execute both Href & Onclick</a>


<iframe id="MyFrame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="5px" height="5px"></iframe>
```

So actually I would like to change the above code, to something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function Link() {
                document.getElementById("MyFrame").href = "iframe_source_url";
            }
    </script>


<a href="www.SomeWebsiteInaNewWindow.com" target="_blank" onClick="take a url value from above into MyFrame">A link that execute both Href & Onclick based of the values that will be taken from the above head script</a>
```

Sorry for the hassle, and thanks again very much.
I'm new here...

Comment: Use `onclick` and enclose attribute value in string.

Comment: do you want to change the link of iframes?

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to do, is to load a page from other website (of mine) into my iframe. It working, but I just want to change the URL to an attribute, so it would be easy to me to change the link when need (I have hundreds of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to do something like that

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="window.open(this.href)" target="iframe_test">Test</a>

<iframe id="iframeid" name="iframe_test" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="300px" height="300px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, but I need also to include the line

onClick=document.getElementById("iframeid")

as i'm calling the iframe from other page.

How the line should be including this both link and iframe in one click?

Thanks.

Comment: To be more clear, I would say that your suggestion looks great, but it's just missing the call to load the link content into my iframe ID. I need to combine the link attribute and the iframe ID in one click using onclick.

Comment: Hi,
I'm sorry, please recheck my update question if you can.
I've tried to apply your answer and found up that I may presented the question incorrectly, as not all the relevant code was appeared on top. Can you please see my new edited code for the last minutes?

Comment: Thank you very much! You just solved it for me.
I've upvoted for you, but keep in mind this website policy says you won't see your votes as much as you don't have at least 15 recorded reputation.
Thanks!

Comment: You need name to set iframe as target for loading page and id if you want to style it with css.

Comment: can you please show me the relevant JS? I can't find it after refreshing this page. I did click on the answer as solved and upvoted you. I don't understand why it doesn't saved here. It tells me it does saves. Maybe it's some issue with the coockee on my PC. I'll try to restart later and I'll do that again. No problem.

Comment: `<a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="window.open(this.href)" target="iframe_test">Test</a>

<iframe id="iframeid" name="iframe_test" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="300px" height="300px"></iframe>`

Comment: I meant to the JS Head part that should present the second website inside the frame:

<script type="text/javascript">

            function Link() {
                document.getElementById("what should be here?").href = "second website address";
            }
    </script>

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">

        function Link(object) {
           <a object.href="http://www.example.com";
        }
</script>


<a href="#"com" onClick="LinkonClick="window.open(this.href);"" target="iframe_test">Test</a>

<iframe id="iframeid" name="iframe_test" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="300px" height="300px"></iframe>` Code is not important any more, because I misunderstood you.

Comment: Hi, I'm checking why my vote and answered indication are not shows.
Your script works just in a half. I've created a page for it, so it would be more clear. Can you kindly take a look and see my text there? Thank you!
http://cpanel2.secured.co.il/~iherbcoi/test.html

Comment: Now I see your answer as accepted. I also gave you a vote as I said earlier, but it written me that you won't see you records until you have 15 reputations. Sorry, this is not in my control, really. Can you please just check my test page above, as the script still not working perfectly. Thanks!